# Having a trouble when loading a function almost everything I've defined returns an error of that object not being found?

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I've been trying to load up this function that will take data from three different data frames with some baseball data and then produce a fourth frame with averages of that data that is weighted depending on if the player appears in all 3 frames (played all 3 years) or less, and so on.

The data frames are linked by the fact that each has a playerid which is what I'm using to check how many and which years they specifically appear in. I also have a fourth data frame that has a master list of the playerids and corresponding names that I use to establish the list of IDs to check.

Below is what my data frames with the stats look like of which I have 3 spanning back to 2016

```
> head(batters_18)
  player_id       player_name launch_speed launch_angle
1    592450       Aaron Judge         94.7         12.4
2    408234    Miguel Cabrera         94.4          7.3
3    443558       Nelson Cruz         93.9         12.8
4    608336        Joey Gallo         93.8         21.5
5    519317 Giancarlo Stanton         93.7         11.6
6    623520        David Bote         93.5          3.5
```

this is my actual function code

```r
# to combine batting stats from the 3 seasons in the appropriate categories
# but with a weighting of 45% in 2018, 35% in 2017, and 20% in 2016 for sake
# of favoring recent form and performance, but in each seasons all players have
# at least 50 events

combine.batting.stats <- function(batters_16, batters_17, batters_18, playerID_map){

  #using the stats for each year along with the player ID map

  b18 = batters_18
  b17 = batters_17
  b16 = batters_16
  playerID_map = playerID_map
  playerid = playerID_map$MLBID

  # so first my weights with the scenarios being 
  # exists in all 3 years, exits in exactly two, and finally exists exactly one



  # the check for whether something is in a data frame is as below
  # SOMETHING %in% DATAFRAME$COLUMN
  # this should be used to code three different scenarios where I weight 
  # the value of season stats depending on how may seasons they qualify in

  if(playerid %in% b18$player_id = TRUE & playerid %in% b17$player_id = TRUE
     & playerid %in% b16$player_id = TRUE) {

    #calculation for case of 3 year player
    # 18 is 45%, 17 is 35%, and 16 is 20%

    average_launch_speed = (((b18$launch_speed * 0.45) + (b17$launch_speed * 0.35)
                             + (b16$launch_speed * 0.2)) / 3)

    average_launch_angle = (((b18$launch_angle * 0.45) + (b17$launch_angle * 0.35)
                             + (b16$launch_angle * 0.2)) / 3)

  }

  if(playerid %in% b18$player_id = TRUE & playerid %in% b17$player_id = TRUE
     & playerid %in% b16$player_id = FALSE) {

    #calculation for player in b18 and b17 but not b16....should be extended to
    #other 2 year player situations that is b17 and b16 but not b18 as well as
    #b18 and b16 but not b17 (which I would like to skew even more to b18 stats)
    #than players who have played the most recent 2 years to reflect potential 
    #post injury change

    average_launch_speed = (((b18$launch_speed * 0.6) + (b17$launch_speed * 0.4)) 
                            / 2)

    average_launch_angle = (((b18$launch_angle * 0.6) + (b17$launch_angle * 0.4)) 
                            / 2)

  }

  if(playerid %in% b18$player_id = TRUE & playerid %in% b17$player_id = FALSE
     & playerid %in% b16$player_id = TRUE) {

    #in b18 and b16 but not b17


    average_launch_speed = (((b18$launch_speed * 0.6) + (b16$launch_speed * 0.4)) 
                            / 2)

    average_launch_angle = (((b18$launch_angle * 0.6) + (b16$launch_angle * 0.4)) 
                            / 2)

  }

  if(playerid %in% b18$player_id = FALSE & playerid %in% b17$player_id = TRUE
     & playerid %in% b16$player_id = TRUE) {

    #in b17 and b16 but not b18


    average_launch_speed = (((b17$launch_speed * 0.6) + (b16$launch_speed * 0.4)) 
                            / 2)

    average_launch_angle = (((b17$launch_angle * 0.6) + (b16$launch_angle * 0.4)) 
                            / 2)

  }

  # next are those in only one single frame/year
  # this one is only in 18

  if(playerid %in% b18$player_id = TRUE & playerid %in% b17$player_id = FALSE
     & playerid %in% b16$player_id = FALSE){

    average_launch_speed = b18$launch_speed

    average_launch_angle = b18$launch_angle 

  }

  # only in b17

  if(playerid %in% b18$player_id = FALSE & playerid %in% b17$player_id = TRUE
     & playerid %in% b16$player_id = FALSE){

    average_launch_speed = b17$launch_speed

    average_launch_angle = b17$launch_angle 

  }

  #only in b16

  if(playerid %in% b18$player_id = FALSE & playerid %in% b17$player_id = FALSE
     & playerid %in% b16$player_id = TRUE){

    average_launch_speed = b16$launch_speed

    average_launch_angle = b16$launch_angle 

  }

  # returning a data frame from the function
  combined_stats = data.frame(playerid, average_launch_speed, average_launch_angle)

}
```

and then this is the error I get in the console which I just don't understand the issue with my function

```r
> # to combine batting stats from the 3 seasons in the appropriate categories
> # but with a weighting of 45% in 2018, 35% in 2017, and 20% in 2016 for sake
> # of favoring recent form and performance, but in each seasons all players have
> # at least 50 events
> 
> combine.batting.stats <- function(batters_16, batters_17, batters_18, playerID_map){
+   
+   #using the stats for each year along with the player ID map
+   
+   b18 = batters_18
+   b17 = batters_17
+   b16 = batters_16
+   playerID_map = playerID_map
+   playerid = playerID_map$MLBID
+   
+   # so first my weights with the scenarios being 
+   # exists in all 3 years, exits in exactly two, and finally exists exactly one
+   
+   
+   
+   # the check for whether something is in a data frame is as below
+   # SOMETHING %in% DATAFRAME$COLUMN
+   # this should be used to code three different scenarios where I weight 
+   # the value of season stats depending on how may seasons they qualify in
+   
+   if(playerid %in% b18$player_id = TRUE & playerid %in% b17$player_id = TRUE
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"  
  if(playerid %in% b18$player_id ="
>      & playerid %in% b16$player_id = TRUE) {
Error: unexpected '&' in "     &"
>     
>     #calculation for case of 3 year player
>     # 18 is 45%, 17 is 35%, and 16 is 20%
>     
>     average_launch_speed = (((b18$launch_speed * 0.45) + (b17$launch_speed * 0.35)
+                              + (b16$launch_speed * 0.2)) / 3)
Error: object 'b18' not found
>     
>     average_launch_angle = (((b18$launch_angle * 0.45) + (b17$launch_angle * 0.35)
+                              + (b16$launch_angle * 0.2)) / 3)
Error: object 'b18' not found
>     
>   }
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
>   
>   if(playerid %in% b18$player_id = TRUE & playerid %in% b17$player_id = TRUE
Error: unexpected '=' in "  if(playerid %in% b18$player_id ="
>      & playerid %in% b16$player_id = FALSE) {
Error: unexpected '&' in "     &"
>     
>     #calculation for player in b18 and b17 but not b16....should be extended to
>     #other 2 year player situations that is b17 and b16 but not b18 as well as
>     #b18 and b16 but not b17 (which I would like to skew even more to b18 stats)
>     #than players who have played the most recent 2 years to reflect potential 
>     #post injury change
>     
>   }
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
>     
>     
>   data.frame(check.rows = FALSE)
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
>   
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
> # to combine batting stats from the 3 seasons in the appropriate categories
> # but with a weighting of 45% in 2018, 35% in 2017, and 20% in 2016 for sake
> # of favoring recent form and performance, but in each seasons all players have
> # at least 50 events
> 
> combine.batting.stats <- function(batters_16, batters_17, batters_18, playerID_map){
+   
+   #using the stats for each year along with the player ID map
+   
+   b18 = batters_18
+   b17 = batters_17
+   b16 = batters_16
+   playerID_map = playerID_map
+   playerid = playerID_map$MLBID
+   
+   # so first my weights with the scenarios being 
+   # exists in all 3 years, exits in exactly two, and finally exists exactly one
+   
+   
+   
+   # the check for whether something is in a data frame is as below
+   # SOMETHING %in% DATAFRAME$COLUMN
+   # this should be used to code three different scenarios where I weight 
+   # the value of season stats depending on how may seasons they qualify in
+   
+   if(playerid %in% b18$player_id = TRUE & playerid %in% b17$player_id = TRUE
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"  
  if(playerid %in% b18$player_id ="
>      & playerid %in% b16$player_id = TRUE) {
Error: unexpected '&' in "     &"
>     
>     #calculation for case of 3 year player
>     # 18 is 45%, 17 is 35%, and 16 is 20%
>     
>     average_launch_speed = (((b18$launch_speed * 0.45) + (b17$launch_speed * 0.35)
+                              + (b16$launch_speed * 0.2)) / 3)
Error: object 'b18' not found
>     
>     average_launch_angle = (((b18$launch_angle * 0.45) + (b17$launch_angle * 0.35)
+                              + (b16$launch_angle * 0.2)) / 3)
Error: object 'b18' not found
>     
>   }
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
>   
>   if(playerid %in% b18$player_id = TRUE & playerid %in% b17$player_id = TRUE
Error: unexpected '=' in "  if(playerid %in% b18$player_id ="
>      & playerid %in% b16$player_id = FALSE) {
Error: unexpected '&' in "     &"
>     
>     #calculation for player in b18 and b17 but not b16....should be extended to
>     #other 2 year player situations that is b17 and b16 but not b18 as well as
>     #b18 and b16 but not b17 (which I would like to skew even more to b18 stats)
>     #than players who have played the most recent 2 years to reflect potential 
>     #post injury change
>     
>     average_launch_speed = (((b18$launch_speed * 0.6) + (b17$launch_speed * 0.4)) 
+                             / 2)
Error: object 'b18' not found
>     
>     average_launch_angle = (((b18$launch_angle * 0.6) + (b17$launch_angle * 0.4)) 
+                             / 2)
Error: object 'b18' not found
>     
>   }
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
>   
>   if(playerid %in% b18$player_id = TRUE & playerid %in% b17$player_id = FALSE
Error: unexpected '=' in "  if(playerid %in% b18$player_id ="
>      & playerid %in% b16$player_id = TRUE) {
Error: unexpected '&' in "     &"
>     
>     #in b18 and b16 but not b17
>     
>     
>     average_launch_speed = (((b18$launch_speed * 0.6) + (b16$launch_speed * 0.4)) 
+                             / 2)
Error: object 'b18' not found
>     
>     average_launch_angle = (((b18$launch_angle * 0.6) + (b16$launch_angle * 0.4)) 
+                             / 2)
Error: object 'b18' not found
>     
>   }
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
>   
>   if(playerid %in% b18$player_id = FALSE & playerid %in% b17$player_id = TRUE
Error: unexpected '=' in "  if(playerid %in% b18$player_id ="
>      & playerid %in% b16$player_id = TRUE) {
Error: unexpected '&' in "     &"
>     
>     #in b17 and b16 but not b18
>     
>     
>     average_launch_speed = (((b17$launch_speed * 0.6) + (b16$launch_speed * 0.4)) 
+                             / 2)
Error: object 'b17' not found
>     
>     average_launch_angle = (((b17$launch_angle * 0.6) + (b16$launch_angle * 0.4)) 
+                             / 2)
Error: object 'b17' not found
>     
>   }
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
>     
>   # next are those in only one single frame/year
>   # this one is only in 18
>   
>   if(playerid %in% b18$player_id = TRUE & playerid %in% b17$player_id = FALSE
Error: unexpected '=' in "  if(playerid %in% b18$player_id ="
>      & playerid %in% b16$player_id = FALSE){
Error: unexpected '&' in "     &"
>     
>     average_launch_speed = b18$launch_speed
Error: object 'b18' not found
>     
>     average_launch_angle = b18$launch_angle 
Error: object 'b18' not found
>     
>   }
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
>     
>   # only in b17
>   
>   if(playerid %in% b18$player_id = FALSE & playerid %in% b17$player_id = TRUE
Error: unexpected '=' in "  if(playerid %in% b18$player_id ="
>      & playerid %in% b16$player_id = FALSE){
Error: unexpected '&' in "     &"
>     
>     average_launch_speed = b17$launch_speed
Error: object 'b17' not found
>     
>     average_launch_angle = b17$launch_angle 
Error: object 'b17' not found
>     
>   }
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
>   
>   #only in b16
>   
>   if(playerid %in% b18$player_id = FALSE & playerid %in% b17$player_id = FALSE
Error: unexpected '=' in "  if(playerid %in% b18$player_id ="
>      & playerid %in% b16$player_id = TRUE){
Error: unexpected '&' in "     &"
>     
>     average_launch_speed = b16$launch_speed
Error: object 'b16' not found
>     
>     average_launch_angle = b16$launch_angle 
Error: object 'b16' not found
>     
>   }
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
>   
>   # returning a data frame from the function
>   combined_stats = data.frame(playerid, average_launch_speed, average_launch_angle)
Error in data.frame(playerid, average_launch_speed, average_launch_angle) : 
  object 'average_launch_speed' not found
>   
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

Comment: Pay attention to the difference `=` vs. `==`.

Comment: @jogo is that how I assign an object? I've been using '=' because I think it works the same as '<-' in the console, is it bad form? and inside my ifs should I use '==' or '<-' instead?

Comment: It is about this parts: `if(playerid %in% b18$player_id = TRUE & ...)`; imho there you want `==`. ... but `... == TRUE` is not necessary. `(5 > 3) == TRUE` is the same as `(5 > 3)`. But `(5 > 3) = TRUE` gives an error.

Comment: `=` is for assignments, while `==` is for comparison

Comment: @jogo ohhh I understand, when doing the test for whether a player is in a year I should use '==' but what about all the other errors about things being unexpected? And does my code look like it will work otherwise?

Comment: Your code is not minimal and (without the data) not reproducible. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @jogo thanks for that I'm trying to cut the code and data down now - but i also have everything up on github under code here https://github.com/hammadm1012/hits/issues/1

Comment: With your GitHub sources, I am unable to reproduce your error which refers to an `lapply` call which is nowhere in your source code.

Comment: @Parfait sorry I forgot to include that I put the frames in a data list and ran this lapply command in console completed = lapply(data.list, combine.batting.stats)

Comment: You cannot call it like that as your `combine.batting.stats` expects to receive 4 non-optional arguments. Here you expect one data frame argument.

Comment: @Parfait but when using lapply how can I list all four arguments? It always expects one and then the function -- what would I use in its place if I want every line to be tested (that is every player ID in the playerID_map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reconsider your approach with mutually exclusive `if` logic based on `%in%` lists as you will receive the following warnings where the logical expression you test will result in a multiple item logical vector (i.e., `c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, ...)` since the left hand input to `%in%` is not one value:

> In addition: Warning messages: 
> 1: In if (playerid %in% b18$player_id
>   == TRUE & playerid %in% b17$player_id ==  :   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used 
> 2: In if (playerid %in% b18$player_id == TRUE & playerid %in% b17$player_id ==  :   the
>   condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used 
> 3: In
>   if (playerid %in% b18$player_id == TRUE & playerid %in% b17$player_id
>   ==  :   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
>   
> ...

Instead, consider merging all your four data frames together then running your calculations with vectorized `ifelse()` that checks across equal length columns in same data frame:

**Data**

```
batters_16 <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hammadm1012/hits/master/batters_16.csv")
batters_17 <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hammadm1012/hits/master/batters_17.csv")
batters_18 <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hammadm1012/hits/master/batters_18.csv")

playerID_map <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hammadm1012/hits/master/playerID_map.csv")
```

**Function**

```
combine.batting.stats_new <-  function(batters_16, batters_17, batters_18, playerID_map){

  # OUTER JOIN MERGE OF DATA FRAMES
  merge_df <- merge(batters_16, batters_17, by="player_id", suffixes=c("_16", "_17"), all=TRUE)
  merge_df <- merge(merge_df, batters_18, by="player_id", all=TRUE)
  merge_df <- merge(merge_df, playerID_map, by.x=c("player_id"), by.y=c("MLBID"), all=TRUE)

  # ADD TWO NEW COLUMNS
  merge_df <- within(merge_df, {
                            # ALL YEARS INCLUDED 
    average_launch_speed <- ifelse(!is.na(launch_speed) & !is.na(launch_speed_17) & !is.na(launch_speed_16),
                                   (((launch_speed * 0.45) + (launch_speed_17 * 0.35) + (launch_speed_16 * 0.2)) / 3),
                                   # MISSING ONLY 2016
                                   ifelse(!is.na(launch_speed) & !is.na(launch_speed_17) & is.na(launch_speed_16),
                                          ((launch_speed * 0.6) + (launch_speed_17 * 0.4)) / 2,
                                          # MISSING ONLY 2017
                                          ifelse(!is.na(launch_speed) & is.na(launch_speed_17) & !is.na(launch_speed_16),
                                                 ((launch_speed * 0.6) + (launch_speed_16 * 0.4)) / 2,
                                                 # MISSING ONLY 2018
                                                 ifelse(is.na(launch_speed) & !is.na(launch_speed_17) & !is.na(launch_speed_16),
                                                        ((launch_speed_17 * 0.6) + (launch_speed_16 * 0.4)) / 2,
                                                        # MISSING  2016 AND 2017
                                                        ifelse(!is.na(launch_speed) & is.na(launch_speed_17) & is.na(launch_speed_16),
                                                               launch_speed,
                                                               # MISSING  2016 AND 2018
                                                               ifelse(is.na(launch_speed) & !is.na(launch_speed_17) & is.na(launch_speed_16),
                                                                      launch_speed_17,
                                                                      # MISSING  2017 AND 2018
                                                                      ifelse(is.na(launch_speed) & is.na(launch_speed_17) & !is.na(launch_speed_16),
                                                                             launch_speed_16, NA
                                                                      )
                                                               )
                                                        )
                                                 )
                                          )
                                   )
                            )

    average_launch_angle <- ifelse(!is.na(launch_angle) & !is.na(launch_angle_17) & !is.na(launch_angle_16),
                                   (((launch_angle * 0.45) + (launch_angle_17 * 0.35) + (launch_angle_16 * 0.2)) / 3),
                                   ifelse(!is.na(launch_angle) & !is.na(launch_angle_17) & is.na(launch_angle_16),
                                          ((launch_angle * 0.6) + (launch_angle_17 * 0.4)) / 2,
                                          ifelse(!is.na(launch_angle) & is.na(launch_angle_17) & !is.na(launch_angle_16),
                                                 ((launch_angle * 0.6) + (launch_angle_16 * 0.4)) / 2,
                                                 ifelse(is.na(launch_angle) & !is.na(launch_angle_17) & !is.na(launch_angle_16),
                                                        ((launch_angle_17 * 0.6) + (launch_angle_16 * 0.4)) / 2,
                                                        ifelse(!is.na(launch_angle) & is.na(launch_angle_17) & is.na(launch_angle_16),
                                                               launch_angle,
                                                               ifelse(is.na(launch_angle) & !is.na(launch_angle_17) & is.na(launch_angle_16),
                                                                      launch_angle_17,
                                                                      ifelse(is.na(launch_angle) & is.na(launch_angle_17) & !is.na(launch_angle_16),
                                                                             launch_angle_16, NA
                                                                      )
                                                               )
                                                        )
                                                 )
                                          )
                                   )
                             )


  })

  return(merge_df[c("player_id", "average_launch_speed", "average_launch_angle")])

}
```

**Output**

```
output <- combine.batting.stats_new(batters_16, batters_17, batters_18, playerID_map)

# RANDOM SAMPLE OF 10 ROWS
output[sample(nrow(output), 10),]

#      player_id average_launch_speed average_launch_angle
# 156     400091                   NA                   NA
# 984     501745                   NA                   NA
# 291     430001             91.20000            10.700000
# 1911    621020             29.03167             3.548333
# 596     453269                   NA                   NA
# 1723    596142             30.30333             4.211667
# 38      121358                   NA                   NA
# 1733    598265             30.07000             3.570000
# 1153    518886                   NA                   NA
# 591     453214                   NA                   NA
```

You may notice a very low result such as player (596142) which does align to your weighting:

```
sapply(list(batters_16, batters_17, batters_18), 
       function(df) subset(df, player_id == 596142)$launch_speed)
# [1] 92.7 90.8 90.2

((90.2*0.45) + (90.8*0.35) + (92.7*0.2))/3
# [1] 30.30333
```

Comment: that you so much this was a massive help

Comment: No problem. Glad to help!